# ¿Cómo emular la función Aes_Encrypt de MySql en Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, criptografía

Estoy trabajando un sistema en `Visual Studio C#` y la Base de datos está en `MySQL`, en la BD tengo un procedimiento almacenado que recibe como parametros un string y un blob, el string es el usuario y el blob es la contraseña encriptada, necesito desde C# enviar la contraseña encriptada para que pueda comparar valores en la BD.

La contraseña se guarda **encriptada** con la función de MySQL `AES_ENCRIPT(frase,llave)`, como puedo emular esta función en `C#`, he encontrado algunos ejemplos de la función `rijndael` pero usan un valor de inicialización que no entiendo bien para que sirve, el cual en `MySQL` no lo ha pedido, por favor cualquier ejemplo de solución es agradecido.

Comment: Actualmente el encriptado de la contraseña se hace con una función de MySQL en este caso AES_ENCRIPT. Si tu código C# se va conectar a esa BD MySQL. Por que no sigues utilizando la misma función AES_ENCRIPT?

Comment: @J.Ochoa ya resolviste el problema?

Comment: El problema era que necesitaba enviar la contraseña encriptada desde la app a la BD, por eso necesitaba emular la función de encriptado en la app. Lo resolví usando la función rijndael en desde la app C# para todo, es decir, ya no se encripta nada en la BD, todo sale encriptado desde la App al momento de crear los usuarios. En la BD solo se guarda como tal el valor que retorne la función de encriptación